# Codeigniter - 4 how to access/load packages from vendor folder on a shared hosting server

Tags: php, cpanel, codeigniter-4

I have an application based on codeigniter 4, developed locally with vagrant and VirtualBox VM.
Then I moved it to a shared hosting environment, that is based on litespeed server and cpanel.

The application use certain external packages like phpmailer, sendgrid and google oauth that on local development environment I have installed them with composer. Therefore they were installed in the vendor folder by composer.

When switching to the shared hosting  i have moved the codeigniter installation from the public_html folder one level up, in a dedicated folder called ci4, and as instructed by the documentation I have changed in the index.php front controller the $pathsConfig variable indicating the new folder of ci4 installation.

On the shared hosting server I do not have access to the composer and I just copied the vendor folder from the local computer to the shared server (in the ci4 folder).

The application run well until the moment I use a helper that has a function for sending e-mail based on the PHPMailer external package. I am receiving a *Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer'* not found error.
It seems that the application cannot locate de PHPMailer package.
The helper look like this:

```
require_once ROOTPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\Exception;

function send_email($email, $subject, $body, $altbody)
{
   
    $config = config("Custom");
    try {
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        // Server Settings
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // change this to 0 in production environment
        $mail->Timeout = 30;
        $mail->Host = 'email-smtp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com';
        $mail->Port = '587';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = $config->aws_smtp_user; 
        $mail->Password = $config->aws_smtp_password; 
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        //$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;

        // Recipients
        $mail->setFrom($email, 'Contact Form');
        $mail->addAddress('example@domain.com');

        // Content
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->msgHTML($body);
        $mail->AltBody = $altbody;
        $mail->send();
        return ["flag" => true];
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //print_r($mail->ErrorInfo);
        return ["flag" => false, "error" => $mail->ErrorInfo];
    }
}
```

The helper is loaded automatically in the BaseController using the protected $helper variable.

In the Autoload.php config file I have added the PHPMailer source folder to $psr4 variable

```
public $psr4 = [
        APP_NAMESPACE => APPPATH, // For custom app namespace
        'Config'      => APPPATH . 'Config',
        'PHPMailer' => ROOTPATH . 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/'
        ];
```

So my first question is, if on a shared hosting copying the vendor is a good approach or do I need to have access to composer and to run *composer install* command?

If I can copy vendor folder why codeigniter 4 does not sees the third packages located in this folder and how can I solve this issue?

My folder structure is the following:

```
 /home
    bin
    /ci4
      app
      tests
      vendor
      writable
      .env
      .composer.json
      .composer.lock
    etc
    logs
    /public_html
       css
       images
       js
       webfonts
       .htaccess
       index.php
    public_ftp
    tmp
    var
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you show your folder structure? According to the docs, CI4 will autoload from the vendor folder for you, so you shouldn't need the first line - `require_once ROOTPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';`. More info on the folder structure might help.

Comment: I have edit my question to show the folder structure

Comment: What is your ROOTPATH defined as - in Config\Constants.php. Also I'm not seeing your system folder.

Comment: There is no constant ROOTPATH defined in Config\Constants.php. The system folder is in ci4/vendor/codeigniter/framework folder

Comment: After reinstalling codeigniter 4 with softaculous installer I succeeded to make it work. However now the ci4 folder does contain the system folder. I think the first time I just moved the folders of ci4 from my local development VM to the Cpanel server and on the local VM ci4 was installed with composer create-project command, which seems to have a different folder structure according to the docs. Thanks for the tip regarding the missing system folder!

Answer (score 0):

if you installed library with composer you need move all vendor folder to host but if installed manually you need call namesapce of library

```
public $psr4 = [
        APP_NAMESPACE => APPPATH, // For custom app namespace
        'Config'      => APPPATH . 'Config',
        'PHPMailer' => ROOTPATH .  
'My'=>ROOTPATH .  'thirdParty/My/src'
        ];
```

Comment: The fourth line of your example seems that is missing something. It just ends with concatenation operator.